# Why it has slash (\) in php keyword

Tags: php

I saw this code in some library

```
if (\count($this->variablesGlobal) > 0) {
    $this->variables = \array_merge($variables, $this->variablesGlobal);
    $variables = $this->variables;
} else {
    $this->variables = $variables;
}
```

and I wonder why is it has `\` in php keywords.

I read the documentation about count, it simply state `count` and just used `count` in example without `\`

Comment: You don't need it, it is for classes when using namespace

Comment: ``\`` is the namespace separator.